# Desperately looking for a particular anime

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, cartoon

About 30 years or so ago, I remember watching a Japanese cartoon on tv....I can't remember what it was called...but I remember it used scenes directly taken from the first "Star Wars" movie...I remember being amazed that they were able to get away with that, but it was very well put together. I've been looking for it for years...even contacted my friend who had it on VHS back then, but he couldn't remember what it was called either.
Can ANYONE out there help me figure out what this movie was called?  I'd really like to find it again.

Comment: Was it footage from Star Wars, or animated scenes? Were the scenes used as if taking place in the cartoon? Your friend had it on VHS, was it a movie or a series? Any more information would be helpful.

Comment: Could you be thinking of the Star Wars Holiday special? It featured an [animated segment](http://www.moddb.com/groups/star-wars-fan-group/videos/star-wars-holiday-special-boba-fett-cartoon) and scenes from the original film

Comment: No, it wasn't the Holiday Special...I remember that one very well....it was a Japanese space cartoon, and it used scenes taken directly from Star Wars for the battle scenes...tie fighters and star destroyers and all that, as if they belonged in that movie....I keep wanting to think it was something like "Space Cowboy" or something, but I haven't been able to track it down..and I could be completely wrong about the title.

Comment: You might want to flag your question and ask to have your question moved to http://anime.stackexchange.com/ That is their specialty so they might have more insight....

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you mean [Droids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids), the Star Wars cartoon? It was around in 1985-86, and featured Star Wars cuts -- because it was a Star Wars product.

Additionally, there was the loathed Ewoks series the next year.

Answer (score 2):

If it was a music video, you're probably remembering [the Daicon IV animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-840keiiFDE), which was a fan parody (details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daicon_III_and_IV_Opening_Animations)). It does indeed have scenes that include Darth Vader, stormtroopers, TIE fighters, and such. They "got away with it" because it was made to be shown privately at a fan convention; not distributed internationally.

It's relatively short, though, at 6 minutes long; not a full movie.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"See you, space cowboy" is a statement they make in Cowboy Bebop all the time.  Spike's ship kind of looks like a TIE Fighter, I guess.  The show is only about 20 years old, though.

Still my best guess.